# Path animations

Tags: c#, animation, vector, path, uwp

I want to make my path to have animation. This is example code for path:

```
    <Path Stroke="BlueViolet" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="30, 80">
                        <LineSegment Point="50, 80"/>
                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="70, 20" Point2="90, 80" x:Name="qbs1"/>
                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="110, 140" Point2="130, 80" x:Name="qbs2"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="150, 80"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

I want to make it animation create different path:

```
    <Path Stroke="BlueViolet" StrokeThickness="2">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="30, 80">
                        <LineSegment Point="50, 80"/>
                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="110, 140" Point2="130, 80" x:Name="qbs1"/>
                        <QuadraticBezierSegment Point1="70, 20" Point2="90, 80" x:Name="qbs2"/>
                        <LineSegment Point="150, 80"/>
                    </PathFigure>
                </PathGeometry.Figures>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```

Animation code goes like this, but it is not working:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="pointanimation">
        <PointAnimation From="70,20" To="70, 140" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetName="qbs1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point1"/>
        <PointAnimation From="110, 140" To="110, 20" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True" Storyboard.TargetName="qbs2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

I am calling it via button click event:

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        pointanimation.Begin();
    }
```

I need it to make animation like this:

[image]

Where am I making a mistake? What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `EnableDependentAnimation="True"` on each `PointAnimation` for this to work.

So change the Storyboard like this:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="pointanimation">
    <PointAnimation From="70,20"
                    To="70,140"
                    EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                    AutoReverse="True"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="qbs1"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point1"/>
    <PointAnimation From="110, 140"
                    To="110, 20"
                    EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                    RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                    AutoReverse="True"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="qbs2"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Point1"/>
</Storyboard>
```

You need to set this because of the potential performance implications. ([MSDN link on DependentAnimations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointanimation.enabledependentanimation).